# Cannot get angular.isString to work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to do an `angular.isString` comparison with ng-if inside an ng-repeat. But all items in the array are returned.

So I tried to just output the `angular.isString` result but it doesn't output anything.

Here is what I would like to do:

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
  <div ng-if="angular.isString(item)">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</li>
```

```js
function MyCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.data =
    [
        "Hello",
        "-",
        123
    ];
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m6k13whh/2/

Comment: What does the data array look like?

Comment: Expressions cannot see the `angular` global; a dirty solution is to put angular in the scope: `function MyCtrl($scope) { $scope.angular = angular; ...}`.

Comment: You seem to be using a very old version of Angular (1.0.1) which doesn't have the `ngIf` directive.

Comment: he is using 1.2.1 from jsfiddle and then loading 1.0.1 from external resources

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular expressions are evaluated against the scope. You can create a function which returns `angular.isString`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data">
  <div ng-if="isString(item)">
    {{ item }}
  </div>
</li>

$scope.isString = function(item) {
    return angular.isString(item);
}
```

You can also just filter all of the items with that function:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data | filter:isString">        
   <div>
       {{ item }}     
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to pass reference to angular method into scope

```
$scope.isString = angular.isString
```

then in partial you can just use `ng-if="isString(item)"`

http://plnkr.co/edit/5keCUQrHQnbl4Wg0oKp1?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Hej,

Make sure you only import one library.
Because in the fiddle you have include two angular scripts.
Remove the one in External Resources!

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<!-- this if comparison is what I want to do -->
     <ul>
         <li data-ng-repeat="item in data">
             <div data-ng-if="isString(item)">
                {{ item }}
             </div>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>

 var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.data = [
         "Hello",
         "-",
         123
     ];

     $scope.isString = function(value) {
          return angular.isString(value);
     };
});
```